# Changing post content on save, using updated fields

Tags: permalinks, filters, hooks

**Short:**

I want to change the post's slug (for permalink purposes) upon saving, and use data *I just entered* in the post editor to modify it.

**Long:**

I am currently using the [Tribe Events Calendar](https://theeventscalendar.com/) plug-in, and want to create multiple events with the same title, so to make sure the permalinks are unique, I add the event date (which is stored alongside the post) to the end of the slug on saving the event (post).

**What I have done so far**

I have the permalink update working by using the `save_post` hook:

```
function change_event_slug_on_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && tribe_is_event($post_id) ) {
        // verify post is not a revision, and an event
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $slug = sanitize_title($post->post_title);
        $newslug = $slug . '-' . tribe_get_start_date( $post_id, false, 'j F Y' );
        if ($post->post_name !== $newslug) {
            // unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
            remove_action( 'save_post', 'change_event_slug_on_save' );
            // update the post slug
            wp_update_post( array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_name' => $newslug
            ));
            // re-hook this function
            add_action( 'save_post', 'change_event_slug_on_save', 10, 1 );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'change_event_slug_on_save', 10, 1 );
```

**The problem**

When I change the event's date, I of course want to update the permalink as well. The trouble is: the event date that I just changed, has not yet been changed in the database, so when updating the permalink on `save_post`, it still uses the **last stored** (old) event date. This means I need to save an event (post) *twice* to update the link.

I have tried hooking to `pre_update_post`, but that gives me the same problem. I have also looked into all the hooks Tribe plug-in offers, but found none that offers to hook into an update event.

**Bottom line**: I need to find a way to update the permalink when the post editor's fields are updated (before actually publishing or updating a post), using the fields as they are at the time (and not coming from the database). Any 
help would be very much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [ahendwh2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/112098/ahendwh2)'s answer I fixed it, by hooking into Tribe's `tribe_events_update_meta` hook, the updated code:

```
function change_event_slug_on_save( $post_id, $event_data, $event ) {
    //$event_data holds the changed event data, $event is the actual event (post)
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && tribe_is_event($post_id) ) {
        // verify post is not a revision, and an event
        $slug = sanitize_title($event->post_title);
        $newslug = $slug . '-' . tribe_format_date($event_data['EventStartDate'], false, 'j-F-Y');
        if ($event->post_name !== $newslug) {
            // unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
            remove_action( 'tribe_events_update_meta', 'change_event_slug_on_save' );
            // update the post slug
            wp_update_post( array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_name' => $newslug
            ));
            // re-hook this function
            add_action( 'tribe_events_update_meta', 'change_event_slug_on_save', 10, 3 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'tribe_events_update_meta', 'change_event_slug_on_save', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the post object provided by the action as the second parameter instead of getting it from database:

```
function change_event_slug_on_save( $post_id, $post ) {
    ...
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'change_event_slug_on_save', 10, 2 );
```

With this you can remove the line `$post = get_post($post_id);`

---

**EDIT:**
Tribe Events Calendar has it's own actions for saving an event: `tribe_events_event_save` and `tribe_events_update_meta`. Since the event date is saved in post_meta you should use the second action:

```
/**
 * @param int     $event_id The event ID (alias post ID).
 * @param array   $data     The saved meta fields. The new date should be somewhere in this array
 * @param WP_Post $event    The event itself (alias $post).
 */
function change_event_slug_on_save($event_id, $data, $event) {
    ...
}

add_action('tribe_events_update_meta', 'change_event_slug_on_save', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Good tip, thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't provide me with a way to access the updated event date, as it is not stored inside the post object.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed, thanks! I'll accept your answer and add my updated code to the original question.